# propertyMissing doesn't work in Criteria?

Tags: grails, named-query

So I've got a couple of classes with the following relationship:

```java
class Foo {

    Bar bar
    /* ... other fields ... */

}

class Bar {

    String name

}
```

In class `Foo` I've got a couple of named queries:

```java
static namedQueries = {

    userFoos { user ->

        /* ... get Foos for this user ... */

    }

    limitFoos { colname, dir ->
        order(colname, dir)
    }
```

...which I can then chain together in a controller:

```java
def foos = Foo.userFoos(currentUser).limit(colname, dir)
```

Pretty straightforward so far.  The problem is when I try to sort on `bar`;  I get the error:

```java
could not resolve property: bar.name of: package.Foo.
```

Now, I also got this error when the queries were Criteria that were declared in the controller.  So, I went and wrote a `propertyMissing` handler for `Foo`:

```java
def propertyMissing(String name) {
        if (name.contains(".")) {
            def (String propertyname, String subproperty) = name.tokenize(".")
            if (this.hasProperty(propertyname) && this."$propertyname".hasProperty(subproperty)) {
                return this."$propertyname"."$subproperty"
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this is really the best way to do it, but it did work!  However, now that I've moved the query into the class as a named query, `propertyMissing` doesn't appear to work anymore!  Is this use not supported, or am I just missing something here?

**EDIT**

So I tried moving the Criteria back into the controller and sure enough, the sub-property sort did not work there either! So I guess Criteria just don't support `propertyMissing` at all :/

To answer [dmahapatro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051952/dmahapatro)'s [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417404/propertymissing-doesnt-work-in-namedquery/22432001#comment34089940_22417404), I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to present the information. Clicking on a column header does an AJAX call to a controller action with parameters to indicate which column to sort on and in which direction. Once I determine the column name, I call the named queries like so:

```java
def foosFilteredLimited = params.sSearch ?
    Foo.userFoos(currentUser).filterFoos(params.sSearch).limitFoos(offset, max, colName, sortDir).list()
:   Foo.userFoos(currentUser).limitFoos(offset, max, colName, sortDir).list()
```

(`filterFoos` takes a search string and narrows the results of `userFoos`.)

Comment: Can you exactly show how are you trying to use the named query where you get the exception? I think that is the main part of the question which is missing.

Comment: Have you tried `bar { order("name") }` in your query?

Comment: @SérgioMichels that will definitely work. He wants to generalize the ordering for all properties of Foo. We cannot alias bar to use bar.name inside DetachedCriteria.

Comment: @dmahapatro hey dude :-) How about handling the colname with dot inside the namedQuerie? We can use something like `"$atribute" { order(prop) }`

Comment: @SérgioMichels Yes my dear friend, that was my intention but I did not answer because I felt that was not lucid and I did not test that. Here is the answer. I feel there can be a better approach than this. Feeling lazy on a weekend. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying `limitFoos` namedQuery as below and it should work. There is a caveat to it though. We cannot use `bar.baz.name` if required. ;)

```
limitFoos { column, ord ->
    def colStrs = column.tokenize(/./).toList()

    if( colStrs?.size() > 1 ) {
        "${colStrs[0]}" {
            order( "${colStrs[1]}", ord )
        }
    } else {
        order(column, ord)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the nice thing about `propertyMissing`; it appears to automatically recurse. Fortunately, I don't have any sub-sub-properties to sort on, so that should do the trick! Thanks! :)

Comment: I do have a follow-up question: why use the slashes in tokenize instead of quotes?  I like immediately making a list of the tokens, btw, it's definitely easier to read than multiple assignment.

Comment: It's just a syntactic sugar provided by Groovy to represent slashy strings. Search for "slashy string in Groovy" you would get it. However, with this approach you would not need propertyMissing

Comment: Yeah, it would just be nice if `propertyMissing` worked on Criteria, because then, e.g., `bar.baz.qux.name` would work automatically :)  This solved my problem, though, thanks.